# How can I download a web page's source from Emacs?

Tags: tramp, web, networking

I want to use Emacs as an enhanced way to view the source of a page (say `http://example.com`). Is there some easy way to download the page directly from Emacs, maybe even through `C-x C-f`?

I remember doing this *somehow* in the past (maybe thanks to TRAMP?), but not *how*, and I can't reproduce it any more.

Comment: You mean something more clever than just wget and then viewing that right? Perhaps w3m in emacs gives some kind of option?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: Not necessarily more clever so much as more integrated. For some reason, I think there's a more immediate way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a really quick and dirty solution:

```
(defun my-view-source (url)
  (interactive "MURL: ")
  (switch-to-buffer (url-retrieve url (lambda (_)))))
```

`url-retrieve` is built-in to Emacs; there are also alternatives such as [request.el](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-request).

Answer (score 5):

The [w3](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/w3) mode can do this with the `w3-source-document-at-point` command which by default is bound to `s`.

You could also use `M-!` and invoke `curl`.